# pdfium linking in exisiting file ( using ubuntu)

Tags: c++

I'm struggling to link pdfium to an existing file.
I finally get "libpdfium.a" file and my process has been stuck in linking to an exisiting file.

Therefore, I included libpdfium.a file to my existing file directory, and wrote c-make code as follows..

```
add_library(main SHARED ${directory})              
target_link_libraries(main ${directory}/libpdfium.a )
```

And the error message showed that "undefined referendced to std::_1ctype::id...".

How can I pefectly linking pdfium to exisiting file without these error?

Thanks :)

Comment: Use `link_directories` function to set link directories and then `target_link_libraries` to link libraries with the target without specifying the full path to the library (and its extension too).